# how to android service view overlay fullscreen?? (not activity)

Tags: android

I am developing a lock screen. I tried to implement it by opening a view, not an activity, using a service to block the home key, and the menu key. I succeeded in implementing the screen, but the navigation bar is not hidden like the picture above, not like the picture below. Like the attached code, I put a code that says that it becomes a full screen, but it does not work. What code should I put in to completely cover the view even the navigation bar as in the picture below??

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val inflate = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    wm = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

    var params =
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
        }else{
            WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
        }

    mView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_lock_screen, null)
    mView!!.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)

    setLayout(mView!!)
    customKeypad(mView!!)
    test(mView!!)

    wm!!.addView(mView, params)
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to set `mView!!.systemUiVisibility` after adding the view to window manager.

Comment: seems like it working but not in every phone. for example for Xiaomi with android 8.01 it doesn't work, and navigation bar is visible according to phone settings.